Should questions with Chinese-only titles be precluded from the Hot Network Questions?
My question hit the Hot Network Questions list for all to enjoy (hopefully there's no horrible mistakes):



That's cool and all, but maybe this shouldn't happen.  Proof-of-concept:

Going forward, questions from Spanish Language Stack Exchange will only show in the hot list if they contain some non-trivial amount of English.
Shog9, 2017


Questions without a sufficient amount of English are now not only excluded from the stackexchange.com homepage (that's what you see in the “hot questions” tab of the multicollider), but also from Stack Exchange tweets and SE 2.0 ads.
Emmett, 2011

(Although maybe it's different for language learning sites.)
Question: Should questions with Chinese-only titles be precluded from the Hot Network Questions?
I'm now seeing the question 「批烂斗臭」这个四字词语，除了「批评」强调什么？ on the Hot Network Questions list at, e.g. Politics.SE and History.SE.  I get the impression that Stack Exchange believes this is not possible currently, so I'll tag this as bug.
(I'm not 100% sure other people are seeing the same thing as me: it's my own question in both cases.)

I removed it from the Hot Network Questions.

In my opinion, it should. It is 'hot',  only in Chinese SE, users from other sites in the network are most likely non-Chinese speakers. The 'Hot question' tab means little to them

Hmm... maybe it only shows up on the Chinese.SE page then?

I would have thought that what shows up in HNQ is implemented on the network-side interface rather than the site-side. Wouldn’t they have thought about other languages when they decided to filter out majority-Spanish content from HNQ?
